# Where does a .deb file go after installation?

Tags: 16.04, deb, emulation

I just installed Dolphin 4.0 from a .deb file, where is the application OR how do I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEB files just contain the packaged application, along with some identifiers to tell the OS that it's a DEB, and a few instructions for installation. If you open a DEB and browse it, you'll likely find files under the paths where they'll end up once the DEB is installed.

To open a DEB file you installed, assuming it is one that can be opened, you can either run the command for it in the terminal (Dolphin's is probably `dolphin`) or search for it. First, though, you should reboot. Sometimes the app isn't indexed until reboot, so you won't see an icon for it.

Answer (score 9):

DEB file is actually an archive with control information telling `dpkg` what to do with those files and other stuff ans Zacharee1 has already said. In addition to his answer, you can check where a deb file goes by using this command (after installation)

```
dpkg -L package-name
```

If the deb file name is `dolphin_3.23_amd64.deb`, the first part before `_` is the package name.

This is the output of `dolphin` package

```
→ dpkg -L dolphin
/.
/etc
/etc/xdg
/etc/xdg/servicemenu.knsrc
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/dolphin
/usr/bin/servicemenuinstallation
/usr/bin/servicemenudeinstallation
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kcm_dolphingeneral.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kcm_dolphinviewmodes.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/dolphinpart.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kcm_dolphinnavigation.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kcm_dolphinservices.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdolphinprivate.so.5.0.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/dolphin
/usr/share/doc/dolphin/copyright
/usr/share/doc/HTML
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/locationbar-breadcrumb.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-startup.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/index.cache.bz2
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/nepomuk-search.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/viewproperties-dialog.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-services.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/locationbar-context-menu.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-general-behavior.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/locationbar-editable.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/toolbar-navigation.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/grouping-view.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-viewmodes-icons.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/locationbar-places-icon.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/toolbar-view-appearance.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/nepomuk-search-more-options.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-navigation.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/default-ui.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/toolbar.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/index.docbook
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/locationbar-kioslaves-menu.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/dolphin/preferences-trash.png
/usr/share/appdata
/usr/share/appdata/org.kde.dolphin.appdata.xml
/usr/share/config.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_generalsettings.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_directoryviewpropertysettings.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_compactmodesettings.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_detailsmodesettings.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_iconsmodesettings.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/dolphin_versioncontrolsettings.kcfg
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop
/usr/share/kxmlgui5
/usr/share/kxmlgui5/dolphinpart
/usr/share/kxmlgui5/dolphinpart/dolphinpart.rc
/usr/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin
/usr/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/dolphin
/usr/share/kservicetypes5
/usr/share/kservicetypes5/fileviewversioncontrolplugin.desktop
/usr/share/dbus-1
/usr/share/dbus-1/services
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service
/usr/share/kservices5
/usr/share/kservices5/kcmdolphinservices.desktop
/usr/share/kservices5/dolphinpart.desktop
/usr/share/kservices5/kcmdolphinnavigation.desktop
/usr/share/kservices5/kcmdolphingeneral.desktop
/usr/share/kservices5/kcmdolphinviewmodes.desktop
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdolphinprivate.so.5
/usr/share/doc/dolphin/changelog.Debian.gz
```

After installing a deb file, the generated files that went to `bin` directory can usually be executed. Here we can see 1 entry `/usr/bin/dolphin`, which means you can use `dolphin` command to summon it.